# Using Css to Clear TextBox Text/value

Tags: css, textbox, xhtml, erase

I was wondering, if it was possible to clear a text box with a css code rather than using javascript ?

Comment: +1 for understanding Stack Overflow immediately and asking a good question. Welcome, reza m! :)

Comment: thanks, tho I didn't create an account :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with CSS, only with JS:

Event handler function:

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('IDHERE'), "focus",
function() {
    clearText('IDHERE');
});
```

Event listener function:

```
//addEvent listener
function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    } else {
        if (obj.attachEvent) {
            obj["e" + type + fn] = fn;
            obj[type + fn] = function() {
                obj["e" + type + fn](window.event);
            };
            obj.attachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
        }
    }
}
```

ClearText function:

```
//Clear on focus function
function clearText(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = "";
}
```

This is pure JS, no libraries needed here, very fast and x-browser compatible :)

Comment: I don't understand why the four lines before doing `attachEvent` are neccessary…

Comment: @Nyuszika7H they capture the event as it happens on the DOM element, this eliminates the need for inline JS, It adds the "onclick" event to that DOM element, then call's the clearText function.

Comment: @MylesGray It's pointless to add inline event handlers if you already do `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`. No need for `onclick` at all, even IE6 supports `attachEvent`.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H that is what makes it x-browser, it works right down to netscape, and <IE5, Better safe than sorry

Comment: @MylesGray Yeah, but you add the inline event handlers **IF** `attachEvent` is supported! Suggesting an edit, feel free to reject it but at least look how would I do it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use CSS to manipulate the DOM. In other words: this is not possible.

With CSS one cannot change a document, only the look and behaviour of the document but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. CSS is for presentation only, HTML is for the information and structure and javascript is for DOM manipulation. You will have to use Javascript or one of its libraries to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

can be done, but just in a visual way, it wont actually go, but wont be shown too

there can be many tricks, one can be to set the text color same as the background of your text box, disable selection.

but if you want it to be completely gone you need to use javascript